# Problems solving complex numbers tasks

Tags: complex-numbers

I have some difficulties solving complex numbers task. I have to solve this one:

$z_1 = 3 - 2i$; $z_2 = 1 + 3i$;

I must get $\cfrac{z_1}{z_2}$; $z$ degree $4$; $x$ degree $4 + i = 0$.

Would someone solve or explain please? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Was the objective to compute $\cfrac{z_1}{z_2}$? If not, i'm unsure what your asking?

Comment: What is meant by $z$ degree 4, $x$ degree $4+i=0$?

Comment: Blaze, you are right. z degree 4 i mean z^4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\cfrac{z_1}{z_2}=\cfrac{3 - 2i}{1 + 3i}=\left(\cfrac{3 - 2i}{1 + 3i}\right)\left(\cfrac{1 - 3i}{1 - 3i}\right)=\cfrac{3 - 9i-2i+6i^2}{1 + 3i-3i-9i^2}=-\cfrac{11i + 3}{10}$

$z_1+z_2=(3-2i)+(1+3i)=(3+1)+(3i-2i)=4+i$

For the first part: $\cfrac{z_1}{z_2}$, I simply multiplied it by $1$ in 'disguise': $1=\left(\cfrac{1 - 3i}{1 - 3i}\right)$, we do this to make the denominator of the fraction a real number (we want to get rid of the imaginary part) recall the definition of an imaginary number: $i=\sqrt{-1}$ so $i^{2}=-1$.

For the second part: $z_1+z_2$,  we collect 'like' terms together - in other words you add together the real and imaginary parts correspondingly.

Comment: Could you please explain how do you do these? I am "green" on maths.

Comment: @Jason I have edited my answer with some more detail for you. Hope this helps.